# Specify dotnet publish RuntimeIdentifiers in visual studio

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Probably a simple question, but hard to find the info on.

I can build a test application from the CLI with this:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r rhel.7.2-x64
```

Notice the -r flag, which tells dotnet to build this for redhat 7.2.  That works fine.

How can I get visual studio to add the -r flag when building/debugging through VS? My first instinct was to use a global.json file, but that only lets me change the SDK runtime, not target runtime. Any ideas would be great.

For completness, I am dockerizing the application with a redhat dotnet 2.0 runtime image so i need the bin files to be targeted for that build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a RuntimeIdentifiers XML element to the .csproj file.  Separate multiple identifiers with a semicolon.  Like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;rhel.7.2-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>  
</Project>
```

In Visual Studio, right-click on project > Publish > select the Target Runtime.

[image: Publish Dialog Screenshot]

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried this, but it only ever builds the windows release. I don't see the rhel.7.2-x64 folder inside bin/debug like I get when I do a command line build.

Comment: Did you create a Publish Profile and select the RedHat runtime?  I added a screenshot to my answer to show what I'm referring to.